# Why does checking for a runtime.lastError generate a port error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

After struggling for hours with a weird bug in my actual Chrome extension, I finally managed to nail down the following MCVE:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (typeof request.hello !== "undefined") {
        console.log("I got it!");
    }
});
```

**options.js**

```
// the following gives an error
// chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ hello: true }, function(response) {
//     if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
//         console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
//     }
// });
// the following does not
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ hello: true });
```

As you can probably tell from the comments above, when I add an extra callback function to check for a runtime last error, it gives an error:

> The message port closed before a response was received.

However, when I do not add the callback function, no error is generated!

As as as I can tell from [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), this is the correct format for my callback function:

> If you specify the responseCallback parameter, it should be a function that looks like this: `function(any response) {...};`

Thus, I am failing to understand this inconsistent behaviour. I checked similar questions, and adding `return true` to the `background.js` listener simply delays the occurrence of the error in the first case.

Here's a [zip of the above files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1re3e000VjPUrhxAXJJeKAv7rq915HuJY/view?usp=sharing) to test locally. I am using Chrome 75.

**Update**: I do not intend to send any response from my background js file. It is just a one time message from my options page to the background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, well at least not in my Chrome 75.

The Error Message you see is because you don't answer from your background script, but it's not because you checked for `runtime.lastError`.

If you want to avoid this error, you need to answer from you background script;

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(sender.tab && // check it's actually a tab that talked to us
    typeof request.hello !== "undefined"
  ) {
    sendResponse({received: true}); // or whatever you like
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't intend to send any response from my background page :( Is there any way to fix this without having to send a response

Comment: Don't listen for a response if you don't plan to send one? That callback function is called "*responseCallback*" for a reason.

Comment: But I do need to check if there were no errors in sending the message, don't I?

Comment: From were would the error come? From the background processing? You need to tell your background script to post back what error it encountered. From the sending? Not sure it can happen, but I guess it would be visible directly from your contentscript.